# Problems signing pdf with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, ssl, tcpdf

Im using [tcpdf](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) to generate pdf files and sign them. The problem is that the file Im getting displays "the sign isnt valid" and "Changes have been made in this document" so the sign gets invalidated. The code is as follows:

```
$pdf->SetProtection(array('copy'), '', null, 0, null);

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->Image($imagen, -7, 1, 310, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);

if(!empty($imagentrasera)){
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->Image($imagentrasera, -7, 1, 310, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
}

if(!empty($certificado_digital)){
    // PENDIENTE DE TERMINAR
    $info = array(
    'Name' => __('Certificado PDF',true),
    'Location' => '',
    'Reason' => '',
    'ContactInfo' => '',
    );

    //var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    // HAY QUE RETOCAR¡¡¡
    $certificado_crt = 'file://'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].Configure::read('directorioinstalacion').'app/webroot/Documentos/certificados/'.$certificado_digital;
    $certificado_key = 'file://'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].Configure::read('directorioinstalacion').'app/webroot/Documentos/certificados/'.$certificado_key;

    $pdf->setSignature($certificado_crt,$certificado_key, '', '', 1, $info);
}


echo $pdf->Output(__('Certificado',true).'.pdf', 'I');
```

And im using as an example a p12 generated from [this](https://pkijs.org/examples/PKCS12SimpleExample.html) example page. The parameters im passing to `setSignature` are `$certificate_crt` and `$certificate_key`.

I generated these crt and key files following these steps:

1. `openssl pkcs12 -in example_p12.p12 -out certificate.pem -nodes`
2. Create an empty cert.crt file.
3. Create an empty cert_key.key file.
4. Copy certificate zone from the .pem into the crt file.
5. Copy certificate key zone from the .pem into the key file.

So, i dont know what im doing wrong, it should work this way but im not sure im using the correct certificate files or i should be using different ones like two pem files or something else.. should i use other type of certificate files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the S option on the Output function using tcpdf.

So what i did is this:

```
$content = $pdf->Output(__('Certificado',true).'.pdf', 'S');

$file = fopen("Certificado ".$id_usucert.".pdf", "w+");
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename("Certificado ".$id_usucert.".pdf").'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("Certificado ".$id_usucert.".pdf"));
readfile("Certificado5.pdf");
//Una vez lo hemos bajado lo eliminamos del servidor
unlink("Certificado ".$id_usucert.".pdf");
exit;
```

And this worked like a charm :)